# c++ exception: vector throws exception, but won't show in terminal

Tags: c++, exception

This may be me overlooking something basic, but the code below has no output or exceptions shown in my terminal. (using g++ in Cygwin)
First Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main(){
cout << "main";
vector<string> v;
v.at(0)= "HI";
return 0;
}
```

Second Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main(){
cout << "main" <<endl;
vector<string> v;
try{
v.at(0)= "HI";
}catch(const std::exception &exc){
    cout << exc.what()<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

which has the expected output of :

main

vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)

is there a reason why the first code doesn't give an exception or any output?

Comment: The expected exception gets reported on Linux. Something to do with cygwin's environment, most likely.

Comment: @walnut yes, thanks for linking ill remove for duplicate soon. Does g++ recognize that there is an exception and hence doesn't print main even though the print statement is before the run-time-exception?

Comment: Neither `g++` not `clang++` does such optimizations (unless they have bugs). It'd have observable side effects.

Comment: @TedLyngmo If an exception escapes `main`, then `std::terminate` will be called which in turn calls `std::abort` by default. It is implementation-defined whether stack unwinding is done in that case and static destructors are not called. So `std::cout` wont be flushed, which OP is observing. But yes, the compiler is not allowed to reorder instructions changing the side effects only because there will always be an exception thrown that escapes `main`.

Comment: @OP You need to flush the stream, e.g. by adding `<< endl;` to the `cout` statement. Otherwise the exception is thrown when your output is still in the stream buffer, not flushed yet, and then the uncaught exception will abort the program before the stream can be flushed.

Comment: @walnut Since C++17: `vector() noexcept`. Before C++17, yes, that's possible. - perhaps I'm reading like crap again. I'm just looking at the catching code. :-) Oh, yes ... I am...

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am not sure what you want to say. The exception here is thrown by `.at(0)`, not the constructor.

Comment: @walnut Yeah, but one of my mistakes was looking at the second code snippet only and the constructor was the only one outside the `try` ... `catch`. My bad.

Comment: "_is there a reason why the first code doesn't give an exception or any output?_" - It calls `[[noreturn]] void terminate() noexcept`. since you don't have any exception handler for it. The output may as walnut says be truncated.